# How to extract a frame from a video using python?

Tags: python, image-processing, video, video-streaming

I am trying to capture frame from video stream to do some processing on, however I could not take the stream into python or control it using python, thus I captured it and saved it then I am trying to extract a frame from it but I can't find a way.

Can anyone help me pleas.

Comment: What camera are you using? How is it attached? What Operating System are you using? Which Python version are you using? What code have you got so far? How did you capture the stream a different way? Using what tools? What format is your capture in?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at some libraries for video and image processing such as OpenCV, scikit image or GStreamer for this functionality.

**OpenCV**

Small example for capturing a frame from a video:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Capture a frame from device
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Capture one frame
ret, frame = cap.read()

# Display resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('q'):
  break

# Destroy windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```